# Cannot connect to mysql on php artisan migrate

Tags: mysql, laravel, vagrant, homestead, laravel-migrations

I'm trying to migrate the migrations I created, but i'm experiencing this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'php'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = php and table_name = migrations)

I'm using homestead, and when I run other artisan commands on the vagrant vm everything works fine, I'm working with MacOS high sierra (which I read there was a problem with the new file format and vagrant, but it wasn't my case) and xampp.

I've read everything I've found relating to this issue (it's been two days of suffering). I've tried:

- Using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and viceversa in my .env file
- Typing the exact same configuration of my .env in my config/database.php (but i've read that this is a bad practice, since the configurations are in the env() method, so they take the .env values by default)
- I've changed the mysql port from 3306 to 33060
- I added this line Schema::defaultStringLength(191); to the boot() in appserviceprovider.php
- My user has the right credentials and all privileges, and I created the database before creating the migrations
- When I run netstat -ln | grep mysql on the xampp terminal it returns that the mysql socket port is this:

> unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     86094    /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

Which confuses me, since in my my.cnf file of /etc in xampp the port is set to be 3306, I already tried changing the .env port to 86094 but doesn't work.

When I run the same command (netstat -ln | grep mysql) in the vagrant vm it returns the port of the daemon socket:

> unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     20157    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

I don't know why the same command doesn't return the mysql socket port as well in the vagrant vm.

I'm using Laravel 5.6 with php 7.1.7

Some files as references:

.env

```
B_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=php
DB_USERNAME=php
DB_PASSWORD=php123
```

database.php

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ]
```

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
}
```

Homestead.yaml

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/code
     to: /home/vagrant/code
     type: "nfs"
sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/facturacion/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

Thanks in advance, i'd really appreciate if someone can help me, this is driving me nuts

Comment: `sudo service mysql start`

Comment: also post your homestead.yaml file

Comment: This just sounds like a wrong DB username/password? Double check it :)

Comment: @laravel levaral I restart the mysql server every time I make a change on the .env file, but I do it from the xampp interface. I already updated the question to show you my Homestead.yaml file

Comment: change values of DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD to the values .env file is possessing in database.php file. and change port value in .env to 3306.

Comment: Have you added your db name in `databases:` in `homestead.yaml` file?

Comment: @parthu_panther I already tried that and doesn't work.

Comment: Try: `$ vagrant ssh`. SSH into virtual machine.
`$ vagrant up`. Start virtual machine and then migrate

Comment: @HirenGohel i just added it, but doesn't work

Comment: Change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and see if it's works!

Comment: @HirenGohel Already tried all of that, doesn't work, thanks

Comment: Another NON RECOMMENDED option: Go to your `config\database.php`
remove the `.env` configuration
And set your own credentials

`'mysql' => [
            'host' => '45.55.88.77',
            'database' => 'prod',
            'username' => 'forge',
            'password' => '*********',
        ],`

Comment: @MarilynGarcía: Tried it??

Comment: @HirenGohel yup, and nothing, I forgot to mention that I have my firewall off, in case that was causing problems.

Comment: @MarilynGarcía: Hmm, ok np. May be it cause the problems! not sure..

Answer (score 0):

You are using `vagrant` do this

```
vagrant ssh
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: I run all the artisan commands inside the vagrant vm, I ran vagrant up and then vagrant ssh to access it, this is not the problem.